# Talend- repeat header

Tags: header, talend

I would like to ask if how I can repeat table header for distinct ID record and write it on FileOutputtDelimited
This is my data on tOracleOutput.

```
  `(header)ID  owner   pet   petname
        1   Juicy   Dog   Chrysler
        1   Juicy   Cat   Ming
        1   Juicy   Frog  jush
        2   Miki    Dog   chuchu
        2   Miki    Fish  goldie  `
```

My output on tFileOutput should be like this,

```
       `(header)ID  owner   pet   petname
                1   Juicy   Dog   Chrysler
                            Cat   Ming
                            Frog  jush
        (header) ID  owner   pet   petname
                 2   Miki    Dog   chuchu
                             Fish  goldie`
```

is there a way to repeat header and remove Owner once already existing?

Thank You.

Comment: Please format you question correctly to be able to understand what is you input format and what you expect as output

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a really round about way and I don't really see the use case but it's certainly possible.

You'll want to setup a loop (use a tLoop set to end at the last ID) followed by a filter where you filter by the loop counter. At this point you then unite the data from a tFixedFlowInput component containing the header line and then output this to a tFileOutputDelimited component set to append mode.

This gives you the repeated headers but I'm not 100% sure about how to remove the repeated ID's and owners so will need to think on that a bit.